# Make a plot executable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, cx-freeze

I learnt the existence of `cx_freeze` which allows to make some python file executable. So I tried for an easy example but I wonder if for instance with this file it will work (I tried but it did not work):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
b = np.array([5,2,8,4,6,3,1,5,8,7])

c = plt.plot(a,b,'r.')
plt.show()
```

I ask you this because for me it is not possible to make the plot of python executable? Have you tried to do this? Does it work? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: "I try but it does not work"- You'll need to be more specific. What command/code did you use? What output/error messages did you get?

Comment: What is your `Python` version?

Comment: what platform are you targeting?

Comment: There are 80 entries in the search for ["matplotlib cx_freeze"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=matplotlib+cx_freeze). Some questions don't have an answer, but others do. You should stick to [ask] and detail what you have tried and what the result (error) is. Also add in how far the other questions on this topic are (or aren't) helping.